# How do you make the generated build war contain a build number based on Git commit id?

Tags: java, maven

Using maven, how do you make the generated build war file contain a build number based on Git commit id?

Given that the project is using

```
<groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [FAQ](https://github.com/git-commit-id/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/blob/master/docs/faq.md) gives you what you need:

> Since version 2.1.4 there is a switch to control if you want the
>   plugin to expose the generated properties to your pom as well. This
>   switch is set to false by default to ensure that properties of reactor
>   builds can't be overwritten by accident. Thus if you need this feature
>   set `<injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>` inside
>   the plugin's config.

You should then be able to use something like `<finalName>my-app-${git.commit.id}</finalName>`